# GCP Terraform and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, terraform, bitbucket, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to run terraform files which are in bitbucket using jenkins. I have generated json key file from gcp, I have uploaded it to jenkins as secret file and have tried to use it when building pipeline, with no luck. May I know how to pass .json file from GCP into jenkins?

I have tried to upload json file on my jenkins node and tried to provide its location to the jenkinsfile, this approach too did not work. Installed gcpAuth plugin and tried to provide creds from there, with no luck.

[image]

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = credentials('SE_key')
}
stages {
    stage('checkout') {
        steps {
            //branch//
        }
    }
    stage('Terraform init'){
         steps {
             sh "terraform init -var=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
            }
       }
   }}
```